# predicted rendering of css 3d-transformed pixel

Tags: css, 3d, transformation

I'm working in html, css, and javascript with canvas elements. Sometimes these canvases get css3 3d transformations applied to them (including zooms, rotations, and translations), and I need to predict the 2d-rendered-in-the-browser position of my 3d-transformed canvas, and I'm having some issues with it.

The transformations are actually not being applied to the canvas itself; they're being applied to two container divs around the canvas:

```
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="container-outer">
    <div class="container-inner">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason I have two containers is so I can apply two transformations at once. I have css transitions activated on the transforms, so I can, for example, do an x-translation on one container and a y-translation on the other container, and if they have separate easing functions, the resulting animation is a curve rather than a straight line of motion.

I am attempting to predict the position of the four corners of container-inner. The methods I'm using are correctly predicting the result of translations and zooms, but not rotations. Here's how it works. I start with the known original position of a corner, say [0,0,0]. For the sake of the example, we'll say that all of my divs and my canvas are all 500px x 500px, and I have a perspective of 500px set on the viewport div. So my perspective origin is at [250,250,500]. So I take my known corner position, convert it to a heterogeneous 4x1 vector matrix [0,0,0,1], and use matrixVectorMultiply() to multiply that by the matrix3d css matrix corresponding to the transformation being applied to container-inner. I take the resulting vector and use matrixVectorMultiply() again to multiply it by the matrix3d css matrix corresponding to the transformation being applied to container-outer.

```
matrixVectorMultiply = function(mx, vec)
{ // Given a 4x4 transformation matrix and an xyz vector, this will return the dot product (a new vector)
  if (typeof vec.z == 'undefined')
  {
    vec.z = 0;
  }
  return {
    x: vec.x*mx.array[0] + vec.y*mx.array[1] + vec.z*mx.array[2] + mx.array[3]
    ,y: vec.x*mx.array[4] + vec.y*mx.array[5] + vec.z*mx.array[6] + mx.array[7]
    ,z: vec.x*mx.array[8] + vec.y*mx.array[9] + vec.z*mx.array[10] + mx.array[11]
  };
};
```

'vec' is a simple object with x, y, and z attributes. 'mx' is a simple object with two attributes, 'array' containing a row-primary array representation of the matrix3d transformation array, and 'string' containing a column-primary string representation of that array, ready to be plugged into a CSS transform attribute.

Now I have a 3d coordinate that should be the new position of my corner, after the outer and inner transitions have both been performed. But I need to project that 3d coordinate into my 2d viewing window, with the following function:

```
projection3d = function(pos, origin)
{ // Given an xyz point and an xyz perspective origin point, this will return the xy projected location
  // Using the equation found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Diagram
  var pos2d = {x: null, y: null, z: null},
    relPos2d = {x: null, y: null},
    relPos = {x: null, y: null, z: null};

  // First, we take our given point and locate it relative to the perspective origin, rather than the screen
  relPos.x = pos.x - origin.x;
  relPos.y = pos.y - origin.y;
  relPos.z = pos.z - origin.z;

  // Then we take this object and project it onto our 2d plane
  relPos2d.x = relPos.x * (Math.abs(origin.z) / Math.abs(relPos.z));
  relPos2d.y = relPos.y * (Math.abs(origin.z) / Math.abs(relPos.z));

  // Then we take this and locate it relative to the screen again, instead of the perspective origin
  pos2d.x = relPos2d.x + origin.x;
  pos2d.y = relPos2d.y + origin.y;

  return pos2d;
};
```

I take the result of that function and visually compare it with the actual result of the css 3d transformations in the browser, and find that translations and zooms are being predicted correctly, but not rotations, and I can't for the life of me figure out why not.

Does anyone have any insight? Is there further information I should provide?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but usually a bad result in rotations come from  swaping rows for columns. Thta is, may be the matrix that you have is row-major and you are handling it as col-major, or the opposite. Try experimenting with x: vec.x*mx.array[0] + vec.y*mx.array[4] + vec.z*mx.array[8] or similars...

Comment: @vals Good thought; I'm constantly confusing myself by the fact that the matrix3d() function for css transforms accepts a col-major matrix, when the instinctive way I think of matrices is row-major. That said, I tried your suggestion and edited my matrixVectorMultiply() function accordingly. Unfortunately, that was not the problem. Not only did that not only continue to predict rotations incorrectly, it also started predicting translations incorrectly, when they were correct previously.

Comment: Does this version of the code work as intended in 2020?

Comment: EDIT: this works amazing, thank you for this awesome piece of code!

Comment: @kage23, please, do you have any idea how to [update arc angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939232/how-to-calculate-adjust-x-axis-rotation-for-3d-projected-ellipse) after updating the coordinates with your function?